# Return relevant matrix rows if any combinations of elements of one column sums to x

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix shown below. The next step in the project is to identify spreads. These are being defined as a series of trades composed of at least two different contracts but all of the same product type. The trades making up the spread must happen within 10 minutes and the total volume of buy must equal that of sell. After identifying which rows are related to a spread they should be outputted or tagged for using later. 
Spreads are highlighted in blue for the demo matrix.

[image: Demo matrix of spreads]

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know how to properly slice the time frames.
Then you can create a list which contains all buy/sell values where you count the sell values as a negative ones.

At this point you are only missing the list that contains all combinations of rows in that time window. This list can be created with the help of the itertools module, i.e with:

```
time_window = [1, 2, 3]
for L in range(0, len(time_window)+1):
    for subset in itertools.combinations(time_window, L):
        print(subset)
```

At this point you only test it vs the required value.